# How do I compute swift execution time, independent of CPU sleeping and system clock changes

Tags: swift, macos, benchmarking

I've been looking for something as simple as `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` that does not depend on the system clock staying unchanged, and ignores when the CPU is asleep (so I can run a long running benchmark on my laptop and skip the time it is asleep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a mach call accessible through the foundation framework that does the right thing.  I benchmarked execution times independent of the system clock changing and the CPU sleeping.  Here is a code snippet that can contrast the two methods, and can illustrate how `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` is dependent of the system clock.

```
import Foundation

let t2 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
let t0 = mach_absolute_time()
codeToBenchmark()
let t3 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
let t1 = mach_absolute_time()
let elapsed = Double(t1 - t0) / 1000000000.0
print("--- \(elapsed) \(t3 - t2) seconds ---")
```